# How can I answer a question well on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I have problem when I answer the question on Stack Overflow. There is always a notification like this:

> Some of your past answers have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from answering.
>
> Please pay close attention to the following guidance:
>
> Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
> But avoid …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

Comment: What is *your* question here?

Comment: Presumably the line *"To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers."* contains a link; have you read the linked article(s)? What about those didn't you understand?

Comment: All your non-deleted answers are essentially _Try this: `some code`_ which is a poor answer, you generally want to explain what went wrong in the existing code, and how your change fixes it, instead of asking the OP to try some stuff. I'm also not entirely sure those answers will help, perhaps someone with more PHP experience than me can check

Comment: Did you try reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)? Did you try putting [how to answer on stack overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+answer+on+stack+overflow) into a search engine? Did you try reading and understanding the notification that you quoted? Did you try looking for links in that notification, and following them? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) anything to answer the question yourself?

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this about 13 years ago - I believe it's basically still valid: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/

Comment: this meta post kind of answers the question itself - you hardly spend any time at all. Not on your answers, not on your question. Brevity is a good thing, but being too brief is not a good thing.

Comment: On a tangent: titles are *summaries* of the problem. Treat the post body and the title like spearate entities - they should stand on their own without any surrounding context. Currently, your question body doesn't contain anything that indicates what you are asking for (granted, we can easily infer what you are asking about, but remember - we are a Q&A library, *Meta included*, not a help forum).

Answer (score 16):

Judging from the two visible answers on your account: Both answer are basically

> you can try this
>
> ```
> some code
> ```

Good answers should also explain **why** a certain code change is necessary and **how** it solves the problem. More like

> The problem with your code is XYZ, but instead you need to do ABC. The following code shows you how to fix it:
>
> ```
> some code
> ```

When you explain your answer, it is more likely that people can identify if it also helps with their problem when they search on Stack Overflow. With code only answers, you always have to check what the answer actually does and if it is applicable.

Comment: Personally, my hope with explaining the why and the how is so that someone reading my answer can pass the info along, that they themselves can explain it to someone else, and not just providing an answer that someone can copy and paste.

Comment: Also ideally answers should be confident in their own correctness. "Do this, this is the answer." Not "try this and see if it works". If you aren't sure if an answer is correct, it's often best to refrain from posting it in the first place.